# Xcode scn file white screen

Tags: xcode, scenekit, scnscene

I deleted and reinstalled Xcode, but the problem was not resolved. I click on the scn file and it just opens a white page.

[image]

Comment: did you get the solution

Comment: @Nassif I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

well idk if its gonna help you or not I just imported a .dae file an had the same issue ,but then I went into the materials tab and under transparency I changed it from none to RGB zero (for every material) and it works like magic .Hope this helps you.